# What are J2ME compatible WebDAV libraries?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, webdav

I need a WebDAV library that will work on a BlackBerry, hence J2ME. Having a BSD like license (or other license that would allow use in proprietary applications) would be ideal, but if one can't be had for free, a proprietary pay-for one is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with socket connections like I did:
[StackOverflow: WebDAV with J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716686/webdav-with-j2me)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with WebDAV in J2ME but a quick Google seach turned up a product named [PaderSyncDAV](http://www.pader-sync.com/products.html?mobile_webdav_client)

Comment: I found that, but it itself is an application, where as I need a library in order to build an application.

Comment: Ok. The only WebDAV library I have used in Java is Slide but that is now a defunct project. I have no idea if it worked on J2ME.