# WebDAV with J2ME

Tags: http, sockets, java-me, webdav, midp

Is there a way to use WebDAV with J2ME (some libraries or manual coding)?

I've tried:
- [javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html), but "SEARCH" method not supported there
- [javax.microedition.io.SocketConnection](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/SocketConnection.html) with [Http request](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/23/java_webserver.html) - nothing returns in response
Maybe something wrong with my code or HTTP header:

```
    String response = "";
    String query = "<?xml version='1.0'?> " 
            + "<g:searchrequest xmlns:g='DAV:'> "
            + "<g:sql> "
            + "SELECT 'DAV:displayname' "
            + "FROM 'http://exchangeserver.com/Public/' "
            + "</g:sql> "
            + "</g:searchrequest> ";
    String len = String.valueOf(query.length());
    SocketConnection hc = (SocketConnection) Connector
            .open("socket://exchangeserver.com:8080");
    DataOutputStream dout = 
            new DataOutputStream(hc.openOutputStream());
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(hc.openInputStream());
    String userPass = "username" + ":" + "password";
    byte[] encoded = 
            Base64OutputStream.encode(userPass.getBytes(), 0,
            userPass.length(), false, false);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String request = "SEARCH /Public/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            +"Content-Type:text/xml\r\nContent-Length:"
            + len
            + "\r\nAuthorization:Basic "
            + new String(encoded)
            + "\r\n\r\n";
    bos.write(request.getBytes());
    bos.write(query.getBytes());
    dout.write(bos.toByteArray());
    dout.flush();
    dout.close();
    byte[] bs = new byte[900];
    din.readFully(bs);
    bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bos.write(bs);
    din.close();
    hc.close();
    response = bos.toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julian +1 you was right for Host property, QRSO +1, thanks to all!
So,
- I have found free WebDAV service [MyDisk.se](https://mydisk.se/web/main.php?show=home) (SEARCH not allowed, so I used PROPFIND)
- used [WFetch](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9bfa49bc-376b-4a54-95aa-73c9156706e7&displaylang=en) to play around with WebDAV request
- used [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=f4db40af-1e08-4a21-a26b-ec2f4dc4190d&displaylang=en) to compare requests from WFetch and my app.
:) Finally it's working!
Result code:

```
String response = "";
String query = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\r\n"
        + "<d:propfind xmlns:d='DAV:'>\r\n"
        + "<d:prop><d:getcontenttype/></d:prop>\r\n"
        + "<d:prop><d:getcontentlength/></d:prop>\r\n"
        + "</d:propfind>\r\n";

String len = String.valueOf(query.length());
SocketConnection hc = (SocketConnection) Connector
        .open("socket://79.99.7.153:80");
DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(hc.openOutputStream());
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(hc.openInputStream());
String userPass = "login" + ":" + "password";
byte[] encoded = Base64OutputStream.encode(userPass.getBytes(), 0,
        userPass.length(), false, false);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
String request = "PROPFIND /mgontar/ HTTP/1.1\r\n" 
        + "Depth: 1\r\n"
        + "Host: mydisk.se:80\r\n" 
        + "Accept: */*\r\n"
        + "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n" 
        + "Content-Length: " + len
        + "\r\nAuthorization: Basic " + new String(encoded)
        + "\r\n\r\n";
bos.write(request.getBytes());
bos.write(query.getBytes());
dout.write(bos.toByteArray());
dout.flush();
dout.close();
byte[] bs = new byte[900];
din.readFully(bs);
bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bos.write(bs);
din.close();
hc.close();
response = bos.toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "nothing returns"? No response body? No status code?

I recommend to trace what's going on on the "wire"...

UPDATE: have you tried adding a host header?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Julian. Nothing returns in SocketConnection InputStream (which stands for response). Ok, I'll try to sniff traffic.

Comment: No, I didn't try add host header, I will try that also.

Answer (score 1):

FYI If you are testing on an actual mobile phone, then there is a fair chance your mobile network operator could be blocking non-HTTP traffic.

You might want to first check that you can make GET and POST requests to the server first.